# Google API with .NET Core application

Tags: .net, google-api, gmail, .net-core, google-api-dotnet-client

I want to add gmail connectivity to my .NET Core application. I'm looking at the nuget package

[Google.Apis.Gmail.v1 Client Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Gmail.v1/)

There is mention of .NET Standard 1.3 support, but no mention of .NET Core either in Supported Platforms or Incompatible Platforms. Confused...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all `Google.Apis.*` nuget packages, including `Google.Apis.Gmail.v1`, support .NET Core.

If you look at [this ".NET platforms support" table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library#net-platforms-support), you can see that `.NET Core 1.0` implements `netstandard1.3` (among others). So the `netstandard1.3` support in the Google libraries provides support for .NET Core applications.

So, for example, you can build:

- a .NET Core console app (e.g. targeting netcoreapp1.0)
- an ASP.NET Core application; but note that we don't currently provide simple authentication mechanisms for ASP.NET Core. This be being tracked in github issue [#933](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/933).

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed and informative answer.

Comment: @chris Should core be added to the supported platforms on the NuGet package?

Comment: @DaImTo Yes, it should be made clearer that the netstandard1.3 support provides support for .NET Core; I've created github issue [#1025](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1025) to track.